# Windows powershell show FolderBrowserDialog in taskbar

Tags: windows, powershell

I have windows powershell opening up a dialog to select a file. It works fine and returns the result as needed. However how can I get `.FolderBrowserDialog` to as well appear in the taskbar and keep it `.TopMost` at all times until a folder is selected. My code executes fine with no errors but it doesn't show in the taskbar and when clicking on another window the dialog will get buried behind everything else. I'm stumped

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null

$foldername = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
$foldername.ShowNewFolderButton = $False

$Topmost = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Topmost.TopMost = $True
$Topmost.MinimizeBox = $True
$Topmost.ShowInTaskbar = $True;

$foldername.Description = "Select Your Music Directory"
$foldername.RootFolder = "MyComputer"

$foldername.ShowDialog($Topmost) | Out-Null
return $foldername.SelectedPath
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is not possible as it does not allow an option to showing in the taskbar by design, due to the manner that you are making the call.

When running your code, you will note that it never shows in the taskbar at all even if you don't click on anything else.

Doing this old school, though considered depreciated, which give the same GUI and will show in the taskbar...

***Example***

```
$application = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$path = ($application.BrowseForFolder(0, 'Select a folder', 0)).Self.Path
```

... the drawback here is the it does not automatically show as topmost, thus forcing you to find it on the taskbar to click it to bring it to focus. So, you need to add code to address that.

***Example***

```
$application = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$application.MinimizeAll()
$path = ($application.BrowseForFolder(0, 'Select a folder', 0)).Self.Path
$application.UndoMinimizeALL()
```

So, this, Min/Max, of course could be a bad user experience, you are going to have to weigh that use case.

Now, you can also use the above to ensure that the dialog is always top most and other object cannot be clicked until it is dismissed, by making this modification.

***Example:***

```
$handle = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle
$application = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
($path = ($application.BrowseForFolder([int]$handle, 'Select a folder', 0)).Self.Path)
```

All things considered, IMHO, based on what you are after, you may want create your own WPF GUI for this or a simple launch form for this.

***Rough Example:***

```
$null = Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$form = new-object Windows.Forms.Form 

$dlg = new-object Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog 

$button = new-object Windows.Forms.Button 
$button.Text = "Push me!" 
$button.Dock = "fill" 
$button.add_click({$dlg.ShowDialog()}) 
$form.Controls.Add($button) 

$form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()}) 
$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: I really appreciate the response. Yeah I agree I may have to look for another alternative. I am using phpdesktop for an app and just need it to be able to get user input to select a folder on their drive. I have personally never dove into .net or anything in the visual studio realm. What exactly would you suggest I create to handle this that would take minimal time and learning to accomplish as I don't write in C++ or C#